# how to transpose a dataset, keeping first row as ID python

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

I have this dataset in python:

| statinfo | 2021M08 | 2021M07 | 2021M06 | 2021M05 | 2021M04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AVG,NAC,ALL | 121.55 | 122.32 | 122.83 | 123.01 | 123.1 |
| AVG,NAC,AUD | 1.6118 | 1.5926 | 1.5761 | 1.5653 | 1.5544 |

And I need to transpose the columns headers as values except the first row (want to keep this as column)

Output expected:

| statinfo | Date | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AVG,NAC,ALL | 2021M08 | 121.55 |
| AVG,NAC,ALL | 2021M07 | 122.32 |
| AVG,NAC,ALL | 2021M06 | 122.83 |
| AVG,NAC,ALL | 2021M05 | 123.01 |
| AVG,NAC,ALL | 2021M04 | 123.1 |
| AVG,NAC,AUD | 2021M08 | 1.6118 |
| AVG,NAC,AUD | 2021M07 | 1.5926 |
| AVG,NAC,AUD | 2021M06 | 1.5761 |
| AVG,NAC,AUD | 2021M05 | 1.5653 |
| AVG,NAC,AUD | 2021M04 | 1.5544 |

I have tried `df.transpose()` but it transposes all the dataset, I am a new user using python, any ideas how to do this.

Comment: That isn't any kind of valid python variable - please update your question to at least include the minimum python required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars='statinfo', var_name='Date', value_name='Rate')
      .sort_values('statinfo')

      statinfo     Date      Rate
0  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M08  121.5500
2  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M07  122.3200
4  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M06  122.8300
6  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M05  123.0100
8  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M04  123.1000
1  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M08    1.6118
3  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M07    1.5926
5  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M06    1.5761
7  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M05    1.5653
9  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M04    1.5544
```

Comment: Thank you, this code also worked. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
>>> df.set_index("statinfo") \
      .stack() \
      .reset_index() \
      .rename(columns={"level_1": "Date", 0: "Rate"})

      statinfo     Date      Rate
0  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M08  121.5500
1  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M07  122.3200
2  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M06  122.8300
3  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M05  123.0100
4  AVG,NAC,ALL  2021M04  123.1000
5  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M08    1.6118
6  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M07    1.5926
7  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M06    1.5761
8  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M05    1.5653
9  AVG,NAC,AUD  2021M04    1.5544
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as expected.

Comment: Happy to help! :)